# Shell script with another file variable

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I created a script to install git repo with only one command but i get an error when i want to create the log file.

Here my other script file (GOC_inc.sh)

```
# Repertoire contenant les logs
rep_log=log
```

Here my main script ( i get well the variable $rep_log as logs)

```
# inclusion du fichier de definition des variable
. ./GOC_inc.sh

# Date du jour
date=`date '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'`

# Fichier log

touch $rep_log/install.log

FICLOG= $rep_log/install.log

...
```

When i run the srcipt i get this :

> touch: impossible de faire un touch « log\r/install.log »: Aucun
>   fichier ou dossier de ce type

Why i'm getting this : \r/ ?? hope someone could help.

UPDATE :

```
[root@localhost html]$ xxd GOC_inc.sh
0000000: 2320 5265 7065 7274 6f69 7265 2063 6f6e  # Repertoire con
0000010: 7465 6e61 6e74 206c 6573 206c 6f67 730d  tenant les logs.
0000020: 0a72 6570 5f6c 6f67 3d6c 6f67 0d0a       .rep_log=log..
```

Comment: Sounds like MSWin line ends. Run `dos2unix` or `fromdos`.

Comment: Already try .. ;( same problem

Comment: I am on redhat server

Comment: Show output of `xxd GOC_inc.sh`.

Comment: what command i need to do for this ?

Comment: [xxd](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-xxd/)

Comment: any xxd command is available on redhat/centos packages

Comment: i install it now

Comment: I updated the post with the result of xxd command on the file

Comment: See the `0d` at offset 002c? That's the one. (Also one at 001f but that's harmless as it's in a comment.)

Comment: how could i change this ?

Comment: There are about 12,000 tons of duplicates for this question, it should not be hard to find a solution, especially as I linked this one as a duplicate to a question with several good answers. `dos2unix` is a good one but google for alternatives if you can't find it.

Comment: I done dos2unix on the wrong file ! it's working  many many thanks